Delaying some runs in anylogic parameter variation experiment until others have finished
My parameter variation runs are split into calibration runs and full runs. I would like full runs to only start after calibration runs. Is this possible?

What you are looking for is a Custom Experiment, not a single experiment of Parameter Variation.
In Parameter Variation, the runs are supposed to be independent from each other.
With custom experiment, you can specify and use any kind of desired logic including splits, different loops (one for calibration and one for full run), etc
https://anylogic.help/anylogic/experiments/custom-experiment.html

Thanks a lot for your answer! I’ve been thinking about running 2 ParametersVariation experiments in succession from a custom experiment, one for non-calibrated runs and one for calibrated runs. I’ve been doing this by calling the main function of ParametersVariation, however while the second experiment runs, the experiment window does not launch due to a route mapping error with the Spark library used for the windows. Do you have any suggestions for this issue?

pls always open new issues for new questions, SOF does not work like a forum but like a Q&A place :)
